# Using onclick to Call a Function from within another Function

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table, onclick

I want to identify the HTML Table cell when the mouse is clicked over the menu values in a drop down list. Using W3schools code I can obtain  this information about the cell but not from the drop down list within the cell. 
Somewhere here the DOM is incorrectly setup.

```
<html>
    <td onclick=myFunction5(this)>OPEN</td>
</html>

<script>
function myFunction5(x) {
   alert("Cell index is: " + x.cellIndex);
</script>
```

Using this code for one cell of a HTML table:

```
<td id = "td01" onclick=myFunction5(this)>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Change?</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <p onclick = "displayTableData()">OPEN </p>          
            <p onclick = "displayTableData()">Closed</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</td>
```

Now I need to get the cell id from within another function:-

```
function displayTableData() {
     // when cell onclick - show cell index and contents
    var myTable = document.getElementById('t02');
    var totalRows = document.getElementById('t02').rows.length;
    var totalCol = myTable.rows[0].cells.length;

    document.getElementById(‘td01’).onclick=myFunction5(y);
    var newCellid = y.CellIndex     // return cell id 
}
```

alert - Cell Index is: undefined

Comment: `document.getElementById(‘td01’).onclick = myFunction5(y)` assigns the return value of calling `myFunction5(y)` to the listener. You haven't posted any details of the function. `<html><td ...>...</td></html>` is invalid markup, likely browsers will wrap the td in table, tbody and tr elements.

Comment: Apologies - I thought the HTML code would be unnecessary.
<html><body><table><tr><td onclick=myFunction5(this)>OPEN</td></tr></table></body></html>. 
As for details of the incomplete function - I am stuck - I want to be able to use the Cell Index within the function but have not found a way to extract this information.

Comment: If the click is inside the cell, then it will bubble and call `myFunction5(this)` unless you cancel it. Within *myFunction*, *this* will be the table cell, its *cellIndex* value is revealed by the *cellIndex* property, so `this.cellIndex` (note the capitalisation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you have a table cell with a menu structure inside it. You want to identify the table cell that the menu is in from a click on the menu, which can be achieved by going up the DOM from the event target until you get to the cell (or run out of ancestors).

It's easier if you attach the listeners dynamically, then *this* within the listener will be the element that was clicked on. Otherwise, you have to pass *this* or the event, e.g.

```
<p onclick="displayTableData(this)">Closed</p>
```

or

```
<p onclick="displayTableData(event)">Closed</p>
```

The following should get you going:

```js
// Attach listeners
window.onload = function() {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content p').forEach(
    node => node.addEventListener('click', displayTableData, false)
  );
}

/* Return first ancestor of node that has tagName
** @param {HTMLElement} node - node to start from
** @param {string} tagName - tag name of element to find
** @returns {HTMLElement|undefined} - first matching ancestor or null if none found
*/
function getAncestor(node, tagName) {
  if (!node || !tagName) return;
  while (node.parentNode) {
    node = node.parentNode;
    if (node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return node;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function displayTableData(evt) {
  // Stop bubbling
  evt.stopPropagation();
  var cell = getAncestor(this, 'td');
  console.log(`cellIndex: ${cell && cell.cellIndex}`);
}

function myFunction5(node) {
  console.log(`myFunction5: ${node.tagName} ${node.cellIndex}`);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="td01" onclick="myFunction5(this)">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Change?</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <p>OPEN </p>
          <p>Closed</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There is also [*element.closest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), which should have reasonable support with the above as a fallback.

```js
// Attach listeners
window.onload = function() {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content p').forEach(
    node => node.addEventListener('click', displayTableData, false)
  );
}

function displayTableData(evt) {
  // Stop bubbling
  evt.stopPropagation();
  var cell = this.closest('td');
  console.log(`cellIndex: ${cell && cell.cellIndex}`);
}

function myFunction5(node) {
  console.log(`myFunction5: ${node.tagName} ${node.cellIndex}`);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="td01" onclick="myFunction5(this)">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Change?</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <p>OPEN </p>
          <p>Closed</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you - this solution works a charm - and obviously best solved using Jquery, which I am not conversant with but have now been studying. It would be useful to include the value of the associated cell as well. I am sure all this could be done using Javascript and a comparison of the two would be interesting for me!!

Comment: @Bobtro—there are increasingly fewer reasons to use jQuery. I forgot about [*element.closest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) when writing my answer, it can replace the *getAncestor* function. Most DOM work is now done with frameworks, less and less with POJS.

Comment: Thanks again - this is interesting - I have been trying to use your method to obtain the cell data - OPEN or Closed - associated with the cell index - I need to compare it with the associated cell next door to know whether a change is necessary. So far not successful - any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Bobtro—if you have a different issue, you should ask another question.